# How to apply same steps on different workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, spreadsheet

Suppose I have two folders A and B. In folder A, I have one excel workbook, Total.xlsx. In folder B, I have apple_jan.xlsx, banana_jan.xlsx, coco_jan.xlsx three excel workbooks. Assume all the workbooks only have Sheet1.

I want to copy cells A1:G1 from apple_jan\Sheet1, banana_jan\Sheet1, coco_jan\Sheet1 to Column A, B, C in Total\Sheet1 respectively.

I have to do this every month so I'm wondering how I can simply change the name to apple_feb, banana_feb, coco_feb in one click and automatically change the cell formula of the cells.

I have tried let a random cell let say A2 as a month variable. I wrote "feb" in A2
=[apple_"&A2&".xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1 in Total\Sheet1

I expected it to return the contents of A1 in apple_feb\Sheet1, but it gave me an error. How can I solve this?

Comment: Look into [`INDIRECT`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

Answer (score 0):

```
=INDIRECT("'[apple_" & A2 & ".xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1")
```

all workbooks must be open or linked